# Decoding URI Component in a Flask Application

Tags: python, flask

I am writing a Flask application. In this, I have exposed an API like the following:

```
@app.route("/<project>/<changeId>/<change>/<patch>/<branch>")
def home(project, changeId, change, patch, branch):
    ...................
```

Now, I call this API from my front end code.

Over here, the project variable value that I get is going to be URL Encoded (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp), such that, if the project in Javascript is 
`A/B`, that will be converted to `A%B`

Now, I want to convert it back to `A/B` in my flask application. How can I do that?

I had tried looking at this: https://blog.revathskumar.com/2011/10/python-url-encoding-and-decoding.html

But this doesn't work on what I wish to achieve.

Edit:

So, I did the following:

from urllib import parse

```
@app.route("/<project>/<changeId>/<change>/<patch>/<path:branch>")
def home(project, changeId, change, patch, branch):

app.logger.info('project is %s, changeId is %s, change is %s, patch is %s, branch is %s', project, changeId, change, patch, branch)

    projectnew = parse.unquote(project)

app.logger.info('project is %s, changeId is %s, change is %s, patch is %s, branch is %s', projectnew, changeId, change, patch, branch)
```

Now, strangely when I look at the log lines, the OP for project is same (A) in both the cases even though I pass an encoded string.

For example, the value of project getting is passed is something like: `A%2FB`.

The output after parsing should be `project = A/B`, whereas, in both the cases, the OP is `project = A`

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Doesn't this happen automatically?

Comment: The Flask routing system is inherently RESTful. If you need to pass `A/B` as the value of `project`, you should consider using Query Parameters

Comment: @afro, you mean I cannot parse `project` like the way I did and use the value `A/B` below?

Answer (score 0):

In Python3:

```
>>> from urllib import parse
>>> parse.unquote('https%3A%2F%2Fw3schools.com%2Fmy%20test.asp%3Fname%3Dst%C3%A5le%26car%3Dsaab')
'https://w3schools.com/my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab'
```

In Python2

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.unquote('https%3A%2F%2Fw3schools.com%2Fmy%20test.asp%3Fname%3Dst%C3%A5le%26car%3Dsaab')
'https://w3schools.com/my test.asp?name=st\xc3\xa5le&car=saab'
```

Comment: the output of ```urllib.unquote``` is a string? Or do I need to typecast it?

Comment: The output is type `str`.

Comment: can you please look at my edit once? I incorporated what you suggested but looks like I am going somewhere wrong.